# If I get arrested for having a nuclear weapon, is my right to bear arms being violated?

Tags: united-states, nuclear-weapons, second-amendment

If I were to build my own nuclear weapon, without the intention to detonate it, and got arrested for it, would my second amendment right be being be violated? This is assuming that I had it properly contained and did not put anyone else in danger.

Comment: How is this, at all, related to politics? VTC

Comment: @RickSmith, the 2nd Amendment is very much a political hot potato in the US. Close it as duplicate, not off-topic ...

Comment: @o.m. - The duplicate was closed as off-topic for the same reason I chose for this question.